# More efficient delete of Sql table from DataTable by identifier

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

I have to insert-delete a Sql table using a C# `DataTable`. My two strategies are

1. delete one row at a time, or
2. throw the `DataTable` into a stored procedure and do delete where exists.

Neither strategy is preferred to me as #1 is inefficient and #2 requires some setting up (user schemas, stored procedure, etc.).

Is there another (better) way?

```
//place buy_detail_id into distinct datatable
DataView view = new DataView(table);
DataTable distinctIds = view.ToTable(true, "buy_detail_id");

//strategey 1: delete one row at a time by Id
foreach (DataRow row in distinctIds.Rows)
{
    //delete one row at a time
    DeleteRow(row[0]);
}

//strategy 2: throw DataTable into a stored proc as parameter
//then delete where buy_detail_id exists in distinctIds
```

Comment: Effecient does not mean easy.  #1 is Easy, #2 is Effecient.  Effecient will require setup, no real way around that. In my opinion using stored procedures to simplify your application sql logic is always a better practice.  E.g. instead of having some crazy select in your application code, make a View for it in Sql Server.  Instead of having some crazy Delete query in your application code, make a stored procedure to do it.  The benefit will be performance, as well as ease of maintenance.  You can change a stored procedure's internal workings without having to update any of your app code.

Comment: strategy 2 is not so much work.  I would much prefer it to a database call in a loop.  General instructions already exist on Stack Overflow, find them [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591809/how-to-pass-datatable-parameter-to-stored-procedure-sql-server).

Comment: That stored procedure is only a few lines long. Should be really simple to setup.